# AucteX Citation Color

Tags: auctex, fonts, colors

When inserting a reference in a LaTeX document (using Auctex) I normally type:

```
\cite{joebob_2010}
```

where "\cite" shows up in blue font, while "joebob_2010" shows up reddish/purple.  I like this coloring.  However, when I use

```
\citep{joebob_2010}
```

all text shows up white.

In my .emacs file I put:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
      (font-lock-add-keywords nil   '(("\\(\\\\citep\\)\\s-*{" 1 font-lock-keyword-face t)))
      (font-lock-add-keywords nil   '(("\\(\\\\citet\\)\\s-*{" 1 font-lock-keyword-face t)))
      ))
```

This changed the color of "\citep" to blue, but the reference to "joebob_2010" remains white.  Can I modify this to have the same coloring as "\cite{joebob_2010}"?

**EDIT/SOLUTION**

I posted a bug report to the gnu group for Auctex and found out there was no bug after all.  The following solution works.  In the .emacs file, put:

```
;; set special font highlighting for \cite* commands
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
     (lambda ()
       (font-lock-add-keywords nil  '(("\\(\\\\citep\\)\\s-*{" 1 font-lock-keyword-face t)))
       (font-lock-add-keywords nil  '(("\\(\\\\citet\\)\\s-*{" 1 font-lock-keyword-face t)))
       (font-latex-add-keywords '(("citep" "*[[{")) 'reference)
       (font-latex-add-keywords '(("citet" "*[[{")) 'reference)
       ))
```

Adding the keywords at the end is the key.

Comment: Replace your code with `(setq TeX-parse-self t)`in your init file and restart Emacs. Auctex should then load the relevant style (`natbib.el` or `biblatex.el`) and fontify the macros respectively.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work.  Using this solution not even the "\citep" is colored.  I searched around and was able to find the natbib.el file, but not the bitlatex.el.  Would you suggest that some configuration needs changed?

Comment: Which AUCTeX version are you using? I suggest you update to latest version and check that `biblatex.el` is in a path mentioned in `TeX-style-path` variable. The easiest way is to use elpa to update AUCTeX.

Comment: Strange.  I am running 11.89.5 and my biblatex.el file is in the TeX-style-path.  If you have any more suggestions I would love to hear them, but, since this is an aesthetics issue I can just let it go for now...though it will continue to bug me.

Comment: My last bet is that you open your file and hit `C-c C-n`. You are missing a lot of features provided by that style; you should get it running.

Comment: Ok, I checked the sources, the way I see it `biblatex.el` does not cater for `natbib` compat macros, and [`font-latex.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/font-latex.el#n301) doesn't have them either. Can you please submit a bug report to bug-auctex@gnu.org? Meanwhile,  you can try `\pnotecite` (which is the equivalent IIRC)

Comment: Please move your solution out of the question by posting it as an answer (it's fine to answer your own question).

Comment: Dan, giordano is the one who provided the solution in my bug report, and is posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the solution in the manual ([`(info "(auctex)Fontification of macros")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Fontification-of-macros)):

> Highlighting of macros can be customized by adapting keyword lists which can be found in the customization group `font-latex-keywords`.

Thus you have to issue <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `font-latex-keywords` <kbd>RET</kbd> and then add to the "Font Latex Match Reference Keywords" variable
the new entry with `citep` as "keyword" field and
`*[[{` as "format" field.

In alternative, you can add the following lines to your init file:

```lisp
(add-hook
 'LaTeX-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (font-latex-add-keywords '(("citep" "*[[{")) 'reference)
   (font-latex-add-keywords '(("citet" "*[[{")) 'reference)))
```

---

Cross-reference: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24667